# Authorized API middleware in ASP.NET

Tags: c#, html, asp.net, api, authorization

I'm still learning ASP.NET, this middleware below is a authorized middleware, this will retrieve all the products in my database.

```
    [Authorize]
    // GET: api/ProductsApi
    [HttpGet()]
    public async Task<ActionResult<IEnumerable<Product>>> GetProduct()
    {
        return await _context.Product.Where(p => p.Favorite == false).ToListAsync();
    }
```

This next middleware below is where i try calling the api middleware using it URL ("https://localhost:7009/api/ProductsApi")
and convert the returned data/products into a json and display the products in a razor view page.

```
    public async Task<IActionResult> Index()
    {

        var client = _httpClientFactory.CreateClient();
        var response = await client.GetAsync("https://localhost:7009/api/ProductsApi");

        if (!response.IsSuccessStatusCode)
        {
            return RedirectToAction("Index", "Products");
        }

        var jsonData = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
        List<Product> products = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<Product>>(jsonData);
        return View(products);
    }
```

But i'm getting this error.

[image]

I did some debugging, the problem was, the api returns a login page but does not display it in my web browser, it instead gives me this error page.
Is there anyway to pass the current loggedin user's credentials inside the header or atleast display the login page so i can login instead of this error message?

[image]

Comment: Did you debug and check the value of `jsonData`?

Comment: @Chetan Yes, The value was some html string. And when i change the visualize to HTML visualizer. I get the last image i posted in my question. Which is the actual login page.

Comment: Is `response` status code `301`?

Comment: @RandomSlav No it's 200 actually, but when i convert the data to json, it just gives me a html string like the last image i posted in my question.

Comment: Is the Index code and GetProduct() are in the same we project? Authorize attribute validates that if the request is authenticated and has proper permission to the resource. Your code in Index() does not pass any token or user information to the request that's why api is redirecting to login page

Comment: I hope you are clear about your intention of using [Authorize]

Comment: @Chetan Yes they are in the same project but they're both in different Controller class. The GetProduct() is in ProductsApiController and the index() is in ProductsController.

Comment: @Chetan It's not even redirecting me to the login page, it just give me a error page saying that my jsonData is not valid.

Comment: I'm struggling to understand how does an API return whole View when it's supposed to return simple json data. Did you set up somewhere default return type for all controllers or something like that?

Comment: @GabrielDelaPeña the jsonData variable does not have json string. It has HTML in it. and HTML can not be JSON deserialized. That's why you are getting this error. the HTML is of login page.

Comment: If you're in the same project, there's not a need to use an HttpClient to invoke another endpoint. You're already in server side code, just abstract the logic out from the place you need to call it to be in a 3rd class, then have both controllers invoke that method to obtain the data. Never use an HttpClient to make an app make an HTTP request back to itself.

Comment: change your code like this. that may help you:
var products = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<Product>>(jsonData);
but this should throw an error again.
So do the other ways like this: 
var products = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<list<object>>(jsonData);
if it help you, say it.